# UncaughtExceptionHandler for Errors in Android

Tags: android, exception

I am working on an app with remote exception-handling. That is, if an exception happens somewhere that wasn't expected, the app closes gracefully and a report is generated in the log on our server. I am using the UncaughtExceptionHandler interface for this and it works well except that it does not seem to catch Throwables that are actually Errors.

Obviously, the best solution is to just handle everything and/or not allow anything to throw an Error in the first place. For the sake of thorough error-handling, however, I would like to be able to catch unexpected Errors as well as Exceptions. I was unable to find anything like an UncaughtErrorHandler in Android, does anyone know if such a thing is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generally no way to catch Errors: typically once an Error happens you can't actually intercept it. As far as I know there is no fully-supported mechanism in the Java language to catch these, and there really isn't any one on Android either.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out several SDKs like [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/features.html). A rudimentary way to achieve what you want is to use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`.

Comment: Is Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() any different than Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()? It appears to be the same in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not too sure as I have never used t before.. But there's no way to make sure your application exits gracefully, AFAIK. You'll only be able to do something with that exception with this method.